# Creating a global analytics javascript variable and using those values in Google Analytics / Remarketing

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

So, here's what I'm trying to do. I'm working on an ecommerce system, with multiple analytics entities. I want to create a javascript variable that they can all access.

Checkout page example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   (function(_analytics){

       _analytics.page_type = '$page_type';
       _analytics.cart = null;
       _analytics.order = null;
       _analytics.product = null;

       if( $page_type == 'order_confirmation' ){

          _analytics.order.products = [];
          _analytics.order.total = '$order_total';

          foreach ( $purchased_product ){
             _analytics.order.products.push({
                 'sku' : $sku,
                 'price' : $price,
                 'quantity' : $quantity
             });
          }
       }

    }(_analytics = window._analytics || {}
));
</script>
```

This is the first  tag on my page. After this tag, I include Google analytics, Google remarketing and the other analytics scripts. In those scripts I will loop through the javascript variables that are already created in order to track purchases.

Remarketing tag that comes after the first tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var google_tag_params = {
            ecomm_prodid: '',
            ecomm_pagetype: _analytics.page_type,
            ecomm_totalvalue = _analytics.order.total;
    };

    /* <![CDATA[ */
    var google_conversion_id = XXXXXX;
    var google_custom_params = window.google_tag_params;
    var google_remarketing_only = true;
    /* ]]> */

</script>
```

Are there any disadvantages or gotchas that I should be aware of when trying to implement something like this? Google tag assistant complains that the Google remarketing page type variable is incorrectly set,  but if I console.log(google_tag_params.ecomm_pagetype) I get the correct value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone has a similar problem / question I figured this out. I was using a "dummy" remarketing id to test (0000). Apparently, the remarkting tag didn't like this value. Once I changed it to the actual remarketing id, it worked just fine.